# why is ruby expecting wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I have a  rails app where  I am setting up a method before_save activeRecord callback, like this:

```
class GroupEvent < ApplicationRecord
    enum status: [ :published, :draft ]
    before_save :calculate_and_set_dates
    def calculate_and_set_dates
        missing_properties = []
           #check for available or set attributes 
           puts  "sss" + self.startDate.to_s
             if !self.startDate 
                   missing_properties<<"startDate" 
             end
             if !self.duration 
                missing_properties<<"duration" 
          end
           if !self.endDate
            missing_properties<<"endDate" 
            end
           
            binding.pry

           if  missing_properties.length<=1
             set_missing_property(missing_properties[0]) 
             else
                set_errors_for(missing_properties)
             end

  end

    private
    def set_missing_property(missing_property)
        case  missing_property
         when "startDate"
                 self.startDate = self.endDate - self.duration
         when "duration"
            self.duration = self.endDate -  self.startDate
         when  "endDate"
             self.endDate=  self.startDate +self.duration
        
       end
    end
```

end

Note: this  note the complete class so don't worry about  set_errors_for methods implimentation.

Now when, I create a groupEvent using `GroupEvent.create(name:"hackaton",description:"hecking  my life away",startDate: DateTime.now, duration:10)`. At point where `set_missing_property(missing_properties[0])` is called ,I get an error for wrong number of arguments:

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) from /Users/haroonAzhar/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:15:in startDate'`

As you can see that the method `set_missing_property` has  1 argument  in definition, why is it expecting  0? What's even more confusing is that: when i pass  no argument to the 'set_missing_property' method  I get  this error:

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) from /Users/haroonAzhar/Desktop/develop/whitespectre/app/models/group_event.rb:29:in set_missing_property'`

I don't know why it's looking  at

`/Users/haroonAzhar/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:15:in startDate'`

when I give one  parameter/argument but  i checked out the  file it  was  suggesting  and  the  part  it  is referring to looks  like this:

```
module ClassMethods # :nodoc:
    private
      def define_method_attribute(name)
        ActiveModel::AttributeMethods::AttrNames.define_attribute_accessor_method(
          generated_attribute_methods, name
        ) do |temp_method_name, attr_name_expr|
          generated_attribute_methods.module_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
            def #{temp_method_name}
              name = #{attr_name_expr}
              _read_attribute(name) { |n| missing_attribute(n, caller) }
            end
          RUBY
        end
      end
  end
```

what is  even look for  at  that place when the  defined  method  is  right in the class ? but the real question to which I need answer  is  why is  it  expecting wrong  number  of arguments and how  do I fix it?

Thankyou in advance for your help, really appreciate  it :D

Comment: Just two minor improvements on your coding style. In Ruby community usually uses underscore variable names (`start_date` instead of `startDate`) and idents code with 2 instead of 4 whitespace. Your code, of course, is still fine, but when you want to work together with other Ruby developers in a team in the future then I suggest starting to follow a common Ruby style guide, like the [Ruby Style Guide](https://rubystyle.guide/).

Comment: Thankyou for  that style guide refrence. I primarily work with js, so i'm kinda  new with ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright  guys, I solved it(Maybe)

So at `endDate` case inside my `set_missing_property`, I changed it to:

```
when  "endDate"
         self.endDate =  self.startDate + self.duration
```

I believe I was calling the  self.startDate with a argument which doesnt  expect  any,so it was throwing  that error.

Thanks  for  giving  it a  look to all the  peeps that gave their time to this. really  appreciate  it.

Comment: Whitespace is important. The `+` in `self.startDate +self.duration` would be interpreted as the unary operator so, adding parentheses, that would be seen by Ruby as `self.startDate(+self.duration)`. So be careful and consistent with your whitespace (including indentation).

Comment: Why didn't I get reputation point for  answering  this question?